# Can't pickup id on element inside of div of Iframe

Tags: vb.net, iframe, getelementbyid

Using this Html... from http://www.ebay.com/itm/261901470624?ssPageName=STRK:MESELX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1558.l2649

```
<div id="ds_div">
Yada Yada Yada.
</div>
```

I have tried to capture it using these two methods...

Method 1. (Gave me a null exception)

```
TextBoxDetails.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ds_div").InnerText
```

Method 2. (No errors, no output)

```
Dim PageElement3 As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In PageElement3
    If (CurElement.GetAttribute("id") = "ds_div") Then
        TextBoxDetails.Text = CurElement.GetAttribute("InnerText")
    End If
Next
```

What else is there that I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got this to work. I captured the source of the iframe, and sent it to another browser I set to hidden, then after document completed, I was able to retrieve the item I needed.

Under my "Aquire Data" Button I have this code...

```
'Get Item Details
Dim myFrames As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("iframe")
For Each el As HtmlElement In myFrames
    If el.GetAttribute("id") = "desc_ifr" Then
        WebBrowser2.Navigate(el.GetAttribute("src"))
    End If
Next
```

As my event handler I have this code...

```
Private Sub WebBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser2.DocumentCompleted
    If Not WebBrowser2.Document Is Nothing Then
        TextBoxDetails.Text = WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("ds_div").InnerText
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As I looked, there is no such "ds_div" element, maybe it's created dynamically, but this code worked without exception:

```
    Dim elementId As String = "ds_div"
    Dim PageElement3 As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(elementId)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    If Not PageElement3 Is Nothing Then
        TextBoxDetails.Text = PageElement3.InnerHtml
    Else
        MsgBox("No such element " & elementId & "!")
    End If
```

Try it with ID's like "itemInfoLabel" or "vi-cdown_timeLeft"

Comment: Yeah, it failed. That was like method 1 and 2 mixed. It reports that <div id="ds_div"> is No such element, yet it clearly is there. I have had no difficulty retrieving any of the other items I need from this page, but the details of the item are rather important.

Comment: Can you say where it is? Maybe it appears only if you are logged in or some events happened?

Comment: Oh! I've found it, it's in IFRAME